# Using for_each with std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, lambda, unique-ptr

I'm having the following error when I try to use for_each algorithm with `std::unique_ptr`. I zoomed in on it under *profile.h* section below.

It's odd that I was able to compile if I changed it to `std::shared_ptr`, I suspect that it takes the elements of my container by value and hence doesn't like references to `unique_ptr`s. However, I want it to be `unique_ptr` ideally because these tasks should be placed inside `ToRun_` container and moved over to `Completed_` container once the task has been executed so `shared_ptr` doesn't do me any good here.

The error I'm getting is:

> no matching function for call to object of type '(lambda at Profile.cpp:429:54)'
>
> __f(*__first);

Which refers to this line of code:

```
for_each(ToRun_.begin(), ToRun_.end(), [&os](std::unique_ptr<Task>& e){
  if (e){
    os << e->getName() <<'\n';
  }
});
```

Before I've converted this to use smart pointers, I used raw pointers and I can guarantee that `e->getName()`works 100%. My confusion is why wouldn't it work in this case? What can I do to make it work properly?

### Profile.h

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include "Task.h"
#include "Global.h" //Where my user defined global functions go

class Profile{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Task>>ToRun_;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Task>>Completed_;
  std::vector<std::string>menu_;
  //Ownership of ofstream object
  std::ofstream& of_;
public:
  Profile (const char* filename, std::ofstream& os, ARAIG_sensors& as);
  virtual ~Profile();
  void run();
  //Executes specified number of tasks user specifies
  void execute (unsigned long tasks);
  void load_menu();
  long show_menu()const;
  long getInput(std::string prompt, int min, long max, menuOption option = NONE);
  //Display all tasks to the screen
  std::ostream& display_todo_tasks (std::ostream& os) const;
  //Display completed tasks to the screen
  std::ostream& display_completed_tasks (std::ostream& os)const;
  //Display next task to the screen
  std::ostream& display_next_task (std::ostream& os) const;
  //Display last completed task
  std::ostream& display_last_task(std::ostream& os)const;
};
```

### Profile.cpp

```
std::ostream& Profile::display_todo_tasks(std::ostream& os)const{
  //Display all tasks in ToRun container
  if(ToRun_.size() > 0){
    new_line(user_interface_skip_screen);
    std::cout << "\nTasks to be completed\n";
    print_dash(29);
    for_each(ToRun_.begin(), ToRun_.end(), [&os](std::unique_ptr<Task>& e){
      if (e){
        os << e->getName() <<'\n';
      }
    });
    new_line(user_interface_system_message_skip_line - 1);
  }else{
    std::cerr << "There are no tasks to be performed in the task list.";
    std::cerr.flush();
    new_line(user_interface_system_message_skip_line);
  }
  return os;
}
```

Comment: BTW, any reason you're not just using range-based `for` instead of `for_each`?

Comment: I while I was googling around trying to lear C++, I read somewhere that it is preferred to use algorithms over stand for or range based for loops. I've also been told it's more efficient, hence the use of it. I'm actually not really sure when to use what and I've experienced frustration over unexpected behaviour with std::accumulate in the past.

Comment: Does `for(const auto& e : ToRun_)` seem worse to you than `std::for_each(ToRun_.begin(), ToRun_.end(), [&os](std::unique_ptr<Task>& e)`? The purpose of that statement is to suggest using algorithms when *appropriate*. That is, not resorting to range-based `for` when you're searching, since `std::find` can do that just fine. If the algorithm that fits your problem is `std::for_each`, don't bother.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> std::ostream& Profile::display_todo_tasks(std::ostream& os)const
> ```

Your function is a `const` function. Therefore, `ToRun_` is a `const` object. Therefore, the iterators you get from `begin` and `end` are `const_iterator`s. And therefore, what you get when you dereference them are *`const` references*.

Your lambda takes a non-`const` reference. Hence the incompatibility. Make it take a `const` reference, and it should be fine.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for helping.

Comment: How about validating the answer @geekster01 ?